# Binding a button method to ENTER key

Tags: java, button, javafx, binding, scenebuilder

I have a problem in the program that I am currently working on. The program is with a login-system in which I have a textfield, a passwordfield and two buttons(login and quit).

I want to bind the ENTER key to the "Login" button, so that no matter what it is focused on, if I press the ENTER key in the current scene, it would push the "Login" button. Keep in mind that it still needs to react to mouse clicks.

Comment: You can do that by declaring your input button's type as "submit". Also, make sure that your you entire UI(including textfield's and button) are wrapped inside your <form> tag.

Comment: @rohankangale is that java?

Comment: No. Its should be on your UI/front-end part. i.e. in your HTML code.

Comment: @rohankangale he doesn't use HTML, he is using JavaFX.

Comment: @rohankangale Can you give a code example?

Comment: how about reading the api doc of the classes you are using ... ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for a "Default Button". You can either set it programmatically, or in the Scenebuilder / FXML.

---

## Scenebuilder / FXML

Open your Scene in the Scenebuilder. Then select the button you want to bind <kbd>Enter</kbd> to. Now you can tick "Default Button" on the right panel under *Properties : Button > Specific*. Hit save and that's it.

[image: Scenebuilder example]

This will, in the FXML, add the `defaultButton="true"` attribute to the `<Button>` tag.

---

## Programmatically

In your controller, you need to set `Button#setDefaultButton(boolean)` to `true`. You probably want to do this in the initialization phase of your controller.

Example controller:

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable
{
    @FXML
    private Button button;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
    {
        button.setDefaultButton(true);
    }
}
```

---

You can now press <kbd>Enter</kbd> anywhere in the Scene to simulate a press on that button (and thus executing its listener). Also, a slight blue accent is applied to the button to make it obvious that it is the default button.

Comment: Or by `Button#setDefaultButton(true)` in code, or by `<Button defaultButton="true" />` in FXML.

Answer (score 3):

Simply set the `onAction` event handler for the `Button`, `TextField` and `PasswordField` to the same event handler method. This handler is triggered on <kbd>enter</kbd> if one of those controls is focused and is also triggered, if the button is clicked:

```xml
...
<TextField fx:id="userName" onAction="#submit"/>
...
<PasswordField fx:id="password" onAction="#submit"/>
...
<Button fx:id="loginButton" onAction="#submit"/>
```

#### Controller class

```
@FXML
private void submit() {
    // TODO: login
}
```

Comment: possible ... but violates the _always use the highest abstraction available_ rule ..

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer above, you can try to put the listener on the scene directly to handle multiple keys on a scene.

```
yourScene.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED, //handle event accorddingly);
```

Answer (score -3):

By using the method `javax.swing.JButton#setMnemonic()` you can easily set these buttons to a key in Swing as shown below:

```
theButton.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: Does not exist in JavaFX and does not really answer to the question.

Comment: As @Pagbo said, I tried to look the method up, but found nothing. Neither in JavaFX 2, nor in JavaFX 8. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html

Comment: It comes from Swing/awt.

Comment: @Pagbo my bad, didn't realize you were using javaFX